# Does gcc define anything when -g is specified?

Tags: c, debugging, gcc, c-preprocessor

Shortly, I want to know if gcc (or g++. I need it in **C**, but also am curious about c++) defines any special symbols if `-g` is enabled. Does it? If so, what symbols?

In the search process I found out that:

- `_DEBUG` is defined manually (by manually I mean `-D_DEBUG`) and is a habit taken from Visual C programmers  (because VC defines `_DEBUG` when compiling in debug mode)
- `NDEBUG` is defined if NOT in debug mode. Although I found a few places saying this, I tried with my gcc and g++ in .c and .cpp files and in none of them with or without `-g` no such symbol was defined!

**Edit**: Let me demonstrate why I don't want to use a non-standard symbol:

Imagine a kernel module that does something and also provides header files to be included in other kernel modules so that they can connect to this one.

Now as a facility, in one of the header files I have:

```
#ifdef DEBUG <-- This is what I need
#define LOG(x, ...) printk("Some extra info"x, ##__VA_ARGS__);
#else
#define LOG(x, ...) printk("Without extra info"x, ##__VA_ARGS__);
#endif
```

Note that the name is not really `LOG`, that's an example.

Now, I can use any symbol for `DEBUG` myself, but then if someone includes my header, they may not define that symbol. Of course I can tell them "by the way, to get the headers in debug mode, define this other symbol", but that just doesn't sound right to me.

I could define the symbol in a header and include it in all header files. This way, if they include one of my headers, they get the debug symbol too. The problem now is that, if they *don't* want to compile in debug mode, my headers still think they are in debug mode.

So what I thought would be best was to use a symbol that is defined when `-g` is used, if there are any!

### Update

So far I came to the conclusion that I could do something like this:

how_to_build.h

```
#if !defined(NDEBUG)
#define MY_DEBUG
#endif
```

Usage:

```
#include "how_to_build.h"

#ifdef MY_DEBUG
// rest of the story
```

This way, the common option of `NDEBUG` removes my definition also. It still requires me to tell them to define it if they don't want to get the headers in debug mode.

Comment: The best practise is to always use `-g` because it doesn't affect optimized code or make it any slower. Also, on Unix it is standard to pass `NDEBUG` define to the compiler for release builds and define nothing for debug. Hence you should consider using `NDEBUG` define for telling a debug from release build.

Comment: @MaximYegorushkin, is it standard or just a convention? If it is standard, how come gcc doesn't do it automatically?

Comment: It is a standard convention. C/C++ language doesn't require defining these symbols.

Comment: It's standard in the sense that NDEBUG makes assert.h behave differently.

Comment: "by the way, to get the headers in debug mode, define this other symbol" is the standard way of doing it, IMO.

Answer (score 47, accepted):

You can see the list of all macros gcc/g++ defines for any combination of flags like that:

```
$ g++ -E -dD -xc++ /dev/null
```

For example:

```
[max@truth ~]$ g++ -E -dD -xc++ /dev/null > a
[max@truth ~]$ g++ -E -dD -xc++ -g -O3 /dev/null > b
[max@truth ~]$ diff a b
1a2
> # 1 "/home/max//"
173c174
< #define __NO_INLINE__ 1
---
> #define __OPTIMIZE__ 1
```

Let's see whether `-g` defines anything:

```
[max@truth ~]$ g++ -E -dD -xc++ -g /dev/null > c
[max@truth ~]$ diff a c
1a2
> # 1 "/home/max//"
```

Extra preprocessor directive, but no extra macros for `-g` flag.

---

This makes sense: `-g` has no effect on code-gen, only on object-file metadata (debug *symbols*).

`-O0` is "debug *mode*" code-gen for consistent debugging, as opposed to `-Og` or higher.  ([This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53366394/why-does-clang-produce-inefficient-asm-with-o0-for-this-simple-floating-point) explains what that means in more detail for compilers like gcc and clang: store all variables back to their memory locations after every statement, and don't optimize across statements.)

`-O3` and `-g` are orthogonal (except that you get "optimized out" for some variables when debugging optimized code, and execution appears to jump around between source lines.)

Answer (score 34):

As others have said, and as is apparent from [the manual](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Predefined-Macros.html#Predefined-Macros), GCC does not provide any intrinsic macros that indicate whether debug information will be generated (`-g` mode).  What I want to add, is that this is on purpose.

Long, long ago, the original authors of GCC (RMS, Kenner, probably a couple others) decided that enabling debugging information should not cause *any changes whatsoever* to the actual code, to reduce the risk of a bug [mysteriously vanishing when you try to debug it](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heisenbug).  This is a bedrock design principle in GCC, and even today the developers go out of their way to maintain it.

Defining a macro would violate this design principle, since it would permit the source code to change itself in response to `-g`.

Comment: Very useful answer, good to understand the background to this.

Answer (score 12):

Running
`g++ -E -dD -xc++ /dev/null`
vs.
`g++ -E -dD -g -xc++ /dev/null`
shows me no extra defined symbols.

That, combined with the lack of any documentation stating that symbols get defined, should be enough to safely say that nothing gets defined.